# Multiple inheritance observer pattern implementation in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, final, observers

This is my simplified implementation of half an observer pattern in C++.
It doesn't compile and I have three questions about it:

1. What do I have to do, in order to compile it? The error is:

> error C2259: 'MyClass' : cannot instantiate abstract class 1>
>   due to following members: 1>          'void
>   IObservable::addObserver(void *)' : is abstract 1>
>   e:_projects\test\test.cpp(9) : see declaration of
>   'IObservable::addObserver' 1>          'void
>   IObservable::removeObserver(void *)' : is abstract 1>
>   e:_projects\test\test.cpp(11) : see declaration of
>   'IObservable::removeObserver'

1. Is the "multiple inheritance solution" I use fine in your opinion? I don't want `IMyInterface` to inherit from `AObservable`, because I want implementors of `IMyInterface` to be able implement `IObservable` on their own, if they want to.
2. A little unrelated, but as we are at it. I think `virtual void raiseChanged() final` is more explicit, than just `void raiseChanged()`, in order to tell implementors that I don't want this overridden. Is there any disadvantage of doing this, except of a little performance impact?

Code:

```
class IObservable
{
public:

  virtual void addObserver(void *observer) = 0;

  virtual void removeObserver(void *observer) = 0;
};


class AObservable : public IObservable
{
public:
  AObservable()
    : _observerCount(0)
  {
  }

  virtual void addObserver(void *observer) final override
  {
    ++_observerCount;
  };

  virtual void removeObserver(void *observer) final override
  {
    --_observerCount;
  };

protected:
  virtual void raiseChanged() final
  {
    // call all the observers
  }

private:
  // We just count instead of the data structure
  int _observerCount;
};


class IMyInterface : public virtual IObservable
{
public:
  virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};

class AMyClass : public IMyInterface,
                 public virtual AObservable
{
public:
  virtual void someMethod() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public AMyClass
{
public:
  virtual void someMethod() final override
  {
    //does something
    raiseChanged();
  }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  MyClass cla;
  cla.someMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strange observer pattern you have implemented here. Normally you have one 'Observable' and multiple 'Observers' that can be added to an Observable. The Observable can then call virtual functions to notify the Observers. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Sorry about all the edits, after subclassing, it didn't compile any more. The question also is mainly about multiple inheritance, not observer pattern so I changed that as well.

Comment: remove the inheritance to IObservable from IMyInterface

Comment: Yes dari, but I want every implementation of IMyInterface to also implement IObservable (by contract).

Comment: Ye but right now you are inheriting 2 times from IOobservable and the pure abstract functions from IObservable are only defined from AObservable and not from IMyInterface.

Comment: Exactly. But how do I change this, without changing the design goal? Is it a bad practice? I tried with virtual, with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with complex inheritance issues can often be resolved by using composition instead of inheritance.  In your case, you can treat the `AObservable` as the implementation instead of a superclass:

```
class AMyClass : public IMyInterface
{
  struct : AObservable {
    // Make the protected raiseChanged method public so we can use it.
    using AObservable::raiseChanged; 
  } impl;

public:
  virtual void someMethod() = 0;

  virtual void addObserver(void *observer) override
  {
    impl.addObserver(observer);
  }

  virtual void removeObserver(void *observer) override
  {
    impl.removeObserver(observer);
  }

protected:
  void raiseChanged() { impl.raiseChanged(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually, you do not *really* have multiple inheritance here. What you have is a class that is inheriting an abstract class and *implementing* an interface. (In java this would be much more visible)

   This does not trigger any of the problems with virtual inheritance, namely ["The dreaded diamond-shaped inheritance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) as long as you avoid that you are good.
2. You don't pay any further performance overhead by declaring a function final. As it already is virtual. As a general rule you should always think twice about making a method final, as you should no generalize about how your users may extend your classes. But if you have a VERY good reason for making it final, go ahead.

Comment: I know that there is no "bad" diamont shape here, as I do something that is much more common in Java and C#. The top of the diamond and one side are "interfaces", but in C++ still classes. That is why I do think that I need the "virtual" keyword on the inheritance chain.

Comment: @B3ret That is luckily not a problem, as they are pure virtual functions they still only get one entry in the vtable. It only becomes a problem when there are more than one candidate *implementation* of a function or virtual function.